# unable to call Azure Service Bus from Python

Tags: python, azure

Trying to run the hello world example to put something on the queue, create a queue ... anytime I call azure I get an error.

Here is the code:

```
from azure.servicebus import *

bus_service = ServiceBusService(service_namespace='testtest', account_key='my_access_token', issuer='my_issuer')
bus_service.create_topic('mytopic')
```

Here is the error I get back:

```
$ /c/Python27/python pythontest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pythontest.py", line 4, in <module>
    bus_service.create_topic('mytopic')
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\azure\servicebus\servicebusservice.py", line 1
42, in create_topic
    request.headers = _update_service_bus_header(request, self.account_key, self.iss
uer)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\azure\servicebus\__init__.py", line 185, in _u
pdate_service_bus_header
    request.headers.append(('Authorization', _sign_service_bus_request(request, acco
unt_key, issuer)))
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\azure\servicebus\__init__.py", line 192, in _s
ign_service_bus_request
    return 'WRAP access_token="' + _get_token(request, account_key, issuer) + '"'
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\azure\servicebus\__init__.py", line 233, in _g
et_token
    connection.send(request_body)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\azure\http\winhttp.py", line 313, in send
    self._httprequest.send(request_body)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\azure\http\winhttp.py", line 198, in send
    ctypes.memmove(safearray.pvdata, request, len(request))
WindowsError: exception: access violation writing 0x0000000000000000
```

It always gives me the same error whether I put something on a queue or create a queue, create a topic, send message to a topic, etc.

any ideas?

Comment: lol, miniBSOD. I think no one will help you except microsoft tech support.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the exact code you are using? At least the account_key is not right, it should be in base64 format

```
bus_service = ServiceBusService(service_namespace='testtest', account_key='my_access_token', issuer='my_issuer')
```

Comment: no I stripped out the account key and the issuer. I've created multiple namespaces and created several topics and tried to send messages to them using the different account keys and none of them work. I think the issue is with permissions on the azure side.

Comment: Could you try account_name='weidongtestservicebus2' and account_key='LNkJyAIfeYlGyr3A8Wa7bwQovZ9b1/ZdOEtDr5bhxo0=' and issuer='owner'?  If it works for you, then it maybe the storage account issue.  Which python version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the azure library when used from 64-bit Python.

The changes to make it work are small, so I have listed them here for you.  The fix will be pushed to github + pypi shortly as well.

Make the following changes to **azure/http/winhttp.py**:

Add **c_size_t** to the import statement

```
from ctypes import c_void_p, c_long, c_ulong, c_longlong, c_ulonglong, c_short, c_ushort, c_wchar_p, c_byte, c_size_t
```

Replace **CoInitialize(0)** with

```
CoInitialize(None)
```

Replace the **Com related APIs** section with this

```
_ole32 = oledll.ole32
_oleaut32 = WinDLL('oleaut32')
_CLSIDFromString = _ole32.CLSIDFromString
_CoInitialize = _ole32.CoInitialize
_CoInitialize.argtypes = [c_void_p]

_CoCreateInstance = _ole32.CoCreateInstance

_SysAllocString = _oleaut32.SysAllocString
_SysAllocString.restype = c_void_p
_SysAllocString.argtypes = [c_wchar_p]

_SysFreeString = _oleaut32.SysFreeString
_SysFreeString.argtypes = [c_void_p]

_SafeArrayDestroy = _oleaut32.SafeArrayDestroy
_SafeArrayDestroy.argtypes = [c_void_p]

_CoTaskMemAlloc = _ole32.CoTaskMemAlloc
_CoTaskMemAlloc.restype = c_void_p
_CoTaskMemAlloc.argtypes = [c_size_t]
```